# Как посмотреть консольный вывод

Tags: docker

Как вывести то, что приложение в контейнере написало в консоль?

Нужно не просто подключиться и смотреть новый вывод, а получить вывод за всё время работы

Comment: `docker logs` ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хм, это оказалось проще, чем я думал, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker logs id_container
```

Либо запускать контейнер не в detach моде

```
docker run --name Mycontainername -p 5000:5000 Myimage
```

Тогда всё что происходит в контейнере будет выводится в консоль.